# My passport's 1st laminated page peeled off slightly, but no data/text was disturbed and it just may be lost glue. Will this stop Bali immigration?

Tags: indian-citizens, indonesia, air-india, damaged-passports

I realized my unused Indian passport has very minor damage on the laminated bio page. The laminated page just peeled off a little.

It may be due to glue issue! Will this affect the immigration process in Bali...?

[image: enter image description here][1]]

Comment: By "gum" do you mean "glue"?

Comment: yes I think or I don't know how they laminate

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't seems like much damage.

However, Indian immigration is usually very strict on damage to passport and I have been warned for damages even minor than this when boarding. Since the damage is not significant here, usually they will allow through after warning that to renew it ASAP.

Indonesian immigration was more lax compared to India regarding this and they didn't even ask about minor damages in my passport when entering countless times.

If you want the peace of mind, renew the passport if the trip date is far. You will usually get the passport within 1 week for normal case and 2-3 days for tatkal case.

***In any case, DO NOT attempt to fix it by applying glue or something. Immigration authorities will see this as willfull tampering with passport and will not allow you to fly.***